# Change Seek bar progress color?

Tags: android, android-widget

How i can change the color with gradient???
I have this now,but is different than default way. In default way progress left side is in one color and right is in other(yellow and grey),wat i want is change both colors

`<gradient android:startColor="#FFFFAA00"
            android:endColor="#FFFF0000"
            android:angle="0"/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the link which shows how to customize the Seekbar. I hope this may help you

http://www.tutomobile.fr/realiser-une-progressbar-seekbar-personnalisee-sur-android-tutoriel-android-n%C2%B024/10/02/2011/

http://permadi.com/blog/2011/11/android-sdk-custom-slider-bar-seekbar/

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/androids-seekbar-your-way/943